# Don't see a new branch after creation

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have created a new branch and went with a browser to check if it was created but I don't see it.

```
$ git svn branch -n -m "Students line" student_line --destination branches
Copying https://<my_site>/svn at r294 to https://<my_site>/svn/branches/student_line...
```

Comment: Did you `push` to the appropriate remote repository?

Comment: "https://<my_site>/svn" looks suspicious, does your SVN repository layout support branches at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `-n` switch is a synonym for `--dry-run`:

> **`-n`**
> **`--dry-run`**
>
> This can be used with the dcommit, rebase, branch and tag commands.
>
> For dcommit, print out the series of git arguments that would show which diffs would be committed to SVN.
>
> For rebase, display the local branch associated with the upstream svn repository associated with the current branch and the URL of svn repository that will be fetched from.
>
> For branch and tag, display the urls that will be used for copying when creating the branch or tag.

Remove the `-n` and do it for real.

In general, to sync with Subversion, make sure you have a clean branch, and then update git’s view by running two commands:

```
$ git svn fetch
$ git svn rebase
```